# How to resolve PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process?

Tags: python, shutil

I'm trying to delete 2 sub directories, Folder1 is deleted while Folder 2 is not and I receive this error message when it is not actually used by another process. How to resolve the issue?

Error Message:

> PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'C:/Test/Folder2'

Code:

```
from tkinter import messagebox
import time
import shutil
import os

dirpath = os.path.join('C:/Test/', 'Folder1')
if os.path.exists(dirpath) and os.path.isdir(dirpath):
shutil.rmtree(dirpath)
print('Folder1 removed.')

else:
print('Folder1 does not exist!')
messagebox.showinfo('Click OK.')

dirpath = os.path.join('C:/Test/', 'Folder2')
if os.path.exists(dirpath) and os.path.isdir(dirpath):
shutil.rmtree(dirpath)
print('Folder2 removed.')

else:
print('Folder2 does not exist!')
messagebox.showinfo('Click OK.')
```

Comment: Hmm, maybe you should stop the other process using the directory. Try someting like OpenedFilesView http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/opened_files_view.html

Comment: @stoney, the link doesn't open sorry but thanks